# Create and insert from Temporary table using Linq to SQL in DBML

Tags: .net, linq, sql-server-2008

I am looking to create Temporary table and using LINQ TO SQL .net 3.5

```
CREATE TABLE #InfoDetails
        (
            ID              INT NOT NULL,
            Detail          SMALLINT NOT NULL,
            PKeyID          BIGINT NOT NULL,
            HashValue           VARCHAR(128) NULL, 
            InfoErrors        XML NULL,
            ReasonCode              CHAR(2) NULL,
            ReasonCodeDes             VARCHAR(80) NULL
        )
```

After Creating this temp table insert data in it and after inserting i need to implement SQLBULK copy 
I have no idea how to create Temporary table in .net 3.5 LINQ TO SQL insert data to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use LINQ-to-SQL to insert into a temp table. But you can use `DataContext.ExecuteCommand` to execute arbitrary SQL and perform inserts that way.

You can bulk load using the `SqlBulkCopy` class.

Comment: I am executing this "  int result =   db.ExecuteCommand("CREATE TABLE #ReturnAckDetails(CBRBatchID INT NOT NULL")

Comment: int dropRes = db.ExecuteCommand("DROP TABLE #ReturnAckDetails") : it is giving me exception :  Cannot drop the table '#ReturnAckDetails', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Comment: You need to keep the database connection open to avoid the temp table to be deleted. Put dataContext.Connection into a using block and call dataContext.Connection.Open inside of it.

Comment: If I create (Double Hash) ##TempTable it works fine, if i used single Hash #TempTable it 
gives an Exception :Cannot access destination table 'dbo.#TempTable' on BulkCopy.WriteToServer(tempdata)

Comment: You need to keep the connection open. When you close it the temp table is destroyed.